# Wp Super Cache - Function to reset cache of a specific page

Tags: codex, plugin-wp-supercache

I looked for a solutin like more than hour, but not chance.
There is a function to reset cache of a specific page manually? I'm using wp super cache.

I'm updating some posts meta values using API, and I want when I update something, I reset the cache of this page only. There is a function for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`wpsc_delete_post_cache()`](https://github.com/Automattic/wp-super-cache/blob/4dd110fb37b0989b2ca01db3dacc20a99b4c6f5d/wp-cache.php#L2967)

```
$post_id = 123;
wpsc_delete_post_cache($post_id);
```

Comment: if I can ask, what is the difference with wp_cache_post_change() function?

Comment: While not formally declared as such in the codebase, `wp_cache_post_change()` is more like an event handler. It responds to post edits. And while it does much the same thing as `wpsc_delete_post_cache()`, there are several runtime considerations made by that function, making it slightly less desirable if you're intention is explicitly to clear a specific post ID. Calling `wp_cache_post_change()` may or may not result in the cache being cleared, or it may result in multiple areas of the cache being cleared. It considers constants, actions, and customizable filters.

Comment: Note that `wpsc_delete_post_cache()` also deletes the post author's posts page.

Comment: ok, I didn't understand the last phrase : "deletes the post author's posts page.". what do you mean with posts pages? it delete cache of all posts of that author?